# quadratic reciprocity

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I know $x^2\equiv-7\pmod7$ has solutions. How can I check if $x^2\equiv-7\pmod{49}$ has solutions? I know $-7\equiv42\pmod{49}$ but $49$ isn't a prime so I can't use Euler's criterion. How shall I do this other than check the squares of all numbers modulo $49$?

Comment: Note that $42 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$, so a putative $x$ would have to be divisible by $7$.

Comment: What do you mean by a putative x?

Comment: A hypothetical $x$ with $x^2 \equiv -7 \pmod{49}$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x^2\equiv-7\pmod{49}$, then $7|x$, hence $49|x^2$, which means
$$
x^2\equiv 0\pmod{49}
$$
a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $y \equiv -7 \mod 49$, $y$ is divisible by 7, but not by 49, so $y$ is not a square.

Comment: What does that mean y is not a square?

Comment: Well if some number $y$ statistifies $y \equiv -7 \mod 49$ then $y$ is not a square. In other words, your congruence has no solutions.